# How to iterate over object attributes and check for duplicate in python?

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects stored in a variable. Each object has two attributes: `temp_name` and `temp_body`. Now, I want to iterate through the list of objects and see if the name given by the user already exists in `temp_name` for any object. I tried doing this:

```
temp_name = request.POST.get('temp_name')
templates = EmailTemplate.objects.all()

        for template in templates:
            if template.temp_name == temp_name:
                data = {'status': 'exists'}
                return JsonResponse(data)
            else:
                data = {'status': 'exist_not'}
                return JsonResponse(data)
```

But this only works for the first item in the list, it won't work from the second item onwards. How do I get this working?

Comment: The `return` statements will terminate your loop after one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is returning too early. You need to move `else` part out of the loop to iterate all templates:

```
for template in templates:
    if template.temp_name == temp_name:
        data = {'status': 'exists'}
        return JsonResponse(data)
data = {'status': 'exist_not'}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

BTW, you don't need to use loop. Use [`QuerySet.filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter) to check whether there is matching template exist:

```
temp_name = request.POST.get('temp_name')
exists = EmailTemplate.objects.filter(temp_name=temp_name).exists()
data = {'status': 'exists' if exists else 'exist_not'}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: there is 'fitler' typo

Comment: @AjaySingh, Thank you for your comment. I fixed it accordingly.

Comment: Your first answer works well, but the second answer does not. I get two different errors on it, one for filter like @AjaySingh pointed out and the other for exists, something to do with attribute manager does not have filter or something like that

Comment: @DeA, Is there `temp_name` field in the `EmailTemplate` model? Or did you define custom model manager?

Comment: No, there is a temp_name field in EmailTemplate

Comment: @DeA, Then, `EmailTemplate.objects.filter(temp_name=temp_name).exists()` should work as far as I know. Could you show the full traceback and the model class definition?

Comment: @falsetru Weird, it is working fine now! Thank you! But, I do have a question about this filter thing. Does it differenciate WRT case sensitivity? Because `Test 1` and `test 1` seem to be the same here.

Comment: @DeA, It's case sensitive. If you want case-insensitive comparison, use `...filter(temp_name__iexact=temp_name)`. Maybe dbms you're using can also affect case sensitivity. You might need to check your dbms/db/table configuration.

Comment: Oh wow! Cool! I'll check on this. Where are you getting this from? Is there documentation on this somewhere?